# How to create full color buttons?

Tags: android

I would like to create buttons that have distinctive colors, no text. How can I create such push buttons?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question correctly, you need to have a button which is just like an image, but having an ability to be clicked.

In this case you can use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). The link has an example of how you can define drawables for each state of the button (default, pressed, disabled, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As neutrino said use the ImageButton class. It has one drawback, it's border. To get rid of that border just set the following property in your layout:

- android:background="@null"

This will avoid the border of the button. Now you just need to add a selector to it as the source:

- android:src="@drawable/my_button_selector"